# How can i take text as input and then show it in the notification generated by clicking button?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am making a android app in which user will input the text and click the button. After clicking the button a notification will appear and the notification should show the text entered by user.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't write the code for you. Have you tried following this? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed get the text from the editText

In OnClick method of the button

Generate a notification by below code:

```
// build notification
String content = edtEditText.getText().toString();
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title That you want")
            .setContentText(content).build();


NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Refer to this link for generating notification 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html